# How to get the username and entered password without encoding with spring boot security

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I have implemented the security layer with spring boot security and i have used MD5 encryption mechanism to encode the presented password.It's working perfectly as expected but i need to get username and raw password that user has entered in DAO or service layer.Following is the code i have used

```
@Autowired
UserDao userDao;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
@Autowired
private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**");
}


/**
 * Security implementation to access the services
 */
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/index.html","/home.html","/page/*","/home/*", "/login.html","/login","/cms/createPhoneNo").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    http.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login/authenticate").successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
    http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
    http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).invalidateHttpSession(true);
    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());

    // CSRF tokens handling
    http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}

/**
 * Configures the authentication manager bean which processes authentication
 * requests.
 */
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // Dao based authentication
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
}

private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
    return new AccessDeniedHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.getWriter().append("Access denied");
            response.setStatus(403);
        }
    };
}

/**
 * This bean is load the user specific data when form login is used.
 */
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new MyCustomUserDetailsService(userDao);
}
```

}

Could anybody please help me to achieve this scenario ?

Thanks,

Comment: You can't "decode" md5.  Md5 is a (very weak) one way hash.  Can I ask why you want the raw password?  The point of hashing is to not have this.  Also, consider using at least sha-256 or bcrypt or scrypt, md5 is incredibly weak, and not really appropriate for anything more than checksums.

Comment: @Taylor Actually,i need to check the user authentication with two databases based on the user type.In one db i have the password encoded for the user with user type if that entered user is not found for that user type i need to switch to another db where i have password as raw password so i need the raw password entered.Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: You don't need the raw password. You just hash the password from the database with the same method as in the frontend and compare the hashes.

Answer (score 3):

Add to your `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` method:

```java
auth.eraseCredentials(false);
```

Then you can get the username and password for the *current* user with:

```java
String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
Object rawPassword  = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials();
```

Comment: @holmisWe can use the approach to get once the user has been authenticated.Am i right ?

Comment: @DIVA Yes, when authenticated.

Comment: I need the user credentials before authenticating the user.Then, only i can achieve scenario.Is it possible to use the HttpServletRequest in Dao. I have used like following but i'm getting error like following,          "No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? ".Could you help me out ?

Comment: @DIVA No, you can't revert a hashed password.

Comment: @HomisYes.I agree, but is there any way to get request parameters in Dao.I can get the request parameters in one common class like below code.I would like to use that in Dao.

Answer (score 1):

Before I provide the answer, obligatory warning:

> Storing user passwords in clear text is extremely risky.  Anyone who
>   has access to db has access to user's passwords, which means they can
>   impersonate the user in your application.  Users also tend to reuse
>   passwords, so you expose that user to risks on other systems (their
>   email, their facebook, etc...).

Having that out of the way, oh wait, one more:

> MD5 is an extremely weak one way hash.  It's subject to [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)
>   and plain text to generate a given hash is easily discoverable. 
>   Consider switching to something stronger, like SHA-256, Scrypt,
>   Bcrypt or PBKDF2.

Ok, those done.  Use a `org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PlaintextPasswordEncoder` and apply MD5 (or better, nudge nudge) hash on demand in your DAO.

Comment: How to use this class to get the raw password in daoorg.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PlaintextPasswordEncoder

Comment: @TaylorActually I need of user presented password in Dao like we use HttpServletRequest to get the request parameters.Is it possible ?

Comment: If you use the above, it should be in the auth token.